# How to combine python websockets and other asynchronous tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I have a large python app (now converted to python3) where the main code ran in an infinite loop.

```
while (True):
      #Do loads of stuff, connect to rs485 devices, obtain their status etc.
```

I'm wanting to use websockets with this app. I've now converted it so the structure is:

```
def mainPoll():
    #Do loads of stuff (omitted for brevity)

while (True):
     mainPoll()
```

The websockets sample code ( from [HERE](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)) I have as a starting point is:

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import random
import websockets
async def time(websocket, path):
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"
        await websocket.send(now)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)

start_server = websockets.serve(time, "127.0.0.1", 5678)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

EDIT I've been trying to combine the two. Mycode below will run mainPoll() asynchronously once using create_task. **Is there a better way to keep running it that calling create_task again at the end of mainPoll**?

```py
async def mainPoll():
     #do loads of stuff (omitted for brevity)
     #then create another task to run myself again?!?!?!
     #IS THIS NEXT LINE THE BEST WAY?
     asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(mainPoll())
     #end of mainPoll

async def xtime(websocket, path):
    while True:
        now = str(time.time())
        await websocket.send(now)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)

start_server = websockets.serve(xtime, "0.0.0.0", 5678)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
poll=asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(mainPoll())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I'd really appreciate some pointers here as the websockets code doesn't seem to match any of the asyncio examples I can find. Many thanks.

Comment: You need to make `mainPoll` async as well. Then you call `create_task()` on it and run everything inside the event loop. If you have something that blocks inside `mainPoll`, use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to convert it to an awaitable.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In fact the final example in my question already has mainPoll declared as async and I am already calling create_task on it. That will run it once. What is the best way to keep running it in the event loop? At the moment at the end of mainPoll I create_task again on it and I wasn't sure this is best way.  I'll look up run_in_executor, thanks.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to use `while True` in an async function; have you tried that? I suspect that the problem is that your `mainPoll` isn't awaiting anything because it invokes blocking APIs. That is what the second part of my comment was addressing.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm over complicating this. Fundamental question - If I use "while True" inside an async method, started with create_task, does that stop the event loop running?  Would I would need to be using "await" somewhere in it to avoid it becoming blocking? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Yes, you need to `await` something. That goes for any coroutine or async callback that does something blocking, not just the ones with `while True`. For asyncio to work, everything must fit its paradigm, and legacy blocking code can usually be converted using `run_in_executor` (although that approach has its limitations). Since you never show the code in `mainPoll`, this question is unanswerable as it stands.

Comment: Thanks. Please be assured you have answered the question. I don't show mainPoll as it is hard to summarise and involves lots of classes, essentially it talks to up to four serial ports and polls the status of up to 64 rs485 devices. Nothing blocks as such  (max 10ms timeout per device).   You have helped me understand asyncio. I guess a summary answer would be that there isn't a need to keep recreating the task as long as await methods are used for blocking scenarios within it. I can get away with the code above, but better to be using await and have one task. THANKS

Comment: Nice to hear! I've now added an actual answer with a similar summary, so the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mainPoll` needs to be an async function. There is no need to re-create the task as shown in the question - it is fine for it to contain a `while True` loop, as long as something is awaited inside the loop. If you need blocking APIs there, use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to await them without disturbing websockets.

Comment: An updated answer with "TaskGroup" (python 3.11) could be interesting